# Can't checkout branch in Git

Tags: android, git

I can't checkout branch master in Git after use git command: **git update-index --skip-worktree gradle.properties**.

I used git command: **git update-index --no-skip-worktree gradle.properties** and checkout again. But it's not working.

[Error after use *** git checkout master ***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kipu9.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%E2%80%9CYour+local+changes+would+be+overwritten+by+checkout%22

Answer (score 1):

The message says clearly what is the issue. You have some uncommitted changes.
There are a few ways of handling this issue.

- Ignore this file by adding it to gitignore
- Use git stash to store these changes for future
- Just commit these changes

Comment: Thanks a lot. But It's still not working

Comment: What you did and what is the result. Anything changed?